# Do ID3v2 tags need BOMs?

Tags: music, id3-tag, utf-8, macos

I've noticed an anomaly in ID3v2 tags created by Music.app.  It doesn't affect usability at all, at least not on my system.  But it's odd and might affect how someone else sees the same file.

I have files in several languages, including Greek and Chinese.  So I use Music’s Get Info pop-up to edit Name, Album, Artist, Lyrics, etc.  They all render correctly, including the non-ASCII characters, in Music.  In Terminal, with locale set to "en_US.UTF-8," exiftool also shows them correctly.

I also edit Grouping for sorting factors nothing else in Music provides, including language.  There are NO (zero) non-ASCII characters in any Grouping tag.  Yet exiftool tells me there is "something" (indicated by a dot) at the beginning of every Grouping tag.  Using `exiftool (file) | od -xc` reveals that it is a byte-order-marker (BOM).

Will the **lack** of a BOM on other tags that are UTF-8 cause problems if the file is given to someone with a different CPU/O.S. ?  (I know they are UTF-8.)

Comment: It should not do so if the other applications are coded correctly. UTF-8 does not need a BOM and officially it is not recommended e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom Unfortunately there are many coders who do not read specifications and so there might be an app that breaks but you have to wonder what else it gets wrong.

Comment: I think you have to test it. In my experience some Windows text editors require a Bom to automatically display utf-8 for latin plain text.  Even MacOS TextEdit may need it, I have to check.

Comment: MacOS TextEdit has been used to edit the lyrics (and other files in various languages) before putting them in the ID3 tag.  I don't have access to Windows for testing, but it wouldn't be a text editor.  If I gave someone one of these audio files, the issue would be whether they can play it, and if they can, will the metadata be trashed.

Comment: @mmmmmm, at the Q&A you cited, I see a few things, like (1) a lot of opinionated people can't agree on it; (2) Everything should work without a BOM, but in real life some things won't; (3) even if you use a BOM, some idiot is going to treat it as ISOLatin1 anyway.  Looks like I'm stuck with Tom's comment: sneaker-net the file to a Windows machine and see what happens.

Comment: I see the claim that "there is no endianness in UTF-8" but on Intel MacOS, `od -xc` says the bytes are not in the correct order.

Comment: @WGroleau doesn't -x output shorts (ie 16 bit integers) why can that deal with a file in 8 bit bytes.